# Open div on mouse position on click of svg text in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I want to open a div on click of a text desinged in svg.The div should open at current mouse position.Here is what I have done so far-

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", 500)
.attr("height", 500)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 0 + ")");
svg.append("text")
    .text("ASDSAD")
    .attr("x",20)
    .attr("y",60)
    .attr("onclick",function(d){
    $("#appliedFilters").html("<p>AASDASASDA</p>");
    $("#appliedFilters").show(500).css( {
        position:"absolute", 
        top:event.pageY+10, 
        left: event.pageX
    });
});
```

As you can see I am getting event undefined.I don't know how to get this event object in order to open div on current mouse position...
Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jernovL/9/) i have created.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this way.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 0 + ")");

svg.append("text")
  .text("ASDSAD")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", 60)
  .on("click", function(d) {
    var pos = d3.mouse(this);
    $("#appliedFilters").html("<p>AASDASASDA</p>");
    $("#appliedFilters").show(500).css({
      position: "absolute",
      top: pos[0],
      left: pos[1]
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="appliedFilters"></div>
```